# How do you get a list of Applications on an android app?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

I am currently creating an application for an android mobile phone using eclipse. I have been trying for awhile but can't figure how to get a list of all the current applications installed on the phone on my application. I currently have a database set up on it and a Drop list to populate with the list of applications but can't figure how to get the actual application names themselves? I have looked into different permissions but couldn't find one to do this? Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`PackageManager#getInstalledApplications()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29).